# Robolectric ShadowAssetManager nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android, junit, robolectric

this is the error i get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.open(ShadowAssetManager.java:161)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java)
at dagrada.marco.shariki.MatrixFileReader.getMatrix(MatrixFileReader.java:69)
at dagrada.marco.shariki.GameStatusHandler.loadLevel(GameStatusHandler.java:51)
at dagrada.marco.shariki.GameStatusHandler.loadGame(GameStatusHandler.java:38)
at test.GameStatusHandlerTest.testLoadGame(GameStatusHandlerTest.java:55)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:158)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

And this is the code producing it:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class GameStatusHandlerTest {

@Mock
GraphicsRenderer renderer;


private GameStatusHandler handler;
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;

@Before
public void setUp(){

    context = Robolectric.application.getApplicationContext();
    handler = new GameStatusHandler(context, renderer);


    list.add(0, "level0.txt");

}


@Test
public void testLoadGame(){
    try {
        handler.loadGame(list);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    assertTrue(handler.getCurrentLevel() == 0);
}
```

Through the stactrace it's clear that the code which causes this error is a call to this method, which is a static method in the MatrixFileReader class.

```
public static int[][] getMatrix(Context context, String name) throws Exception {

    int[][] marbles = getMatrix(context.getAssets().open(name));
    return marbles;
}
```

}

Since the stacktrace doesn't go deeper, i guess that the problem is in the context.getAssets.open() method, but i can't figure out the reason, since the pure code is running perfectly onto both the emulator and a real device.

I am probably missing something in the test, which i am trying to run as a junit test.

Comment: Make sure you use the `RobolectricGradleTestRunner` instead of `RobolectricTestRunner`. Where is your other code? What is `new GameStatusHandler(context, renderer);`?

Comment: Since version 3.1.1, this is no longer necessary, @JaredBurrows . See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36564971/1848826

Comment: @hick209 I posted that comment more than a year ago. Now you can just use `RobolectricTestRunner` as `RobolectricGradleTestRunner` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, use RobolectricGradleTestRunner instead of RobolectricTestRunner.
Then make sure that the file you are reading is present in the assets folder of the source code: src/main/assets. 
If you don't want to put it in your test folder, then you will have to specify the test asset folder as one of the asset source in your gradle build like this:

```
sourceSets.main {
    assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/test/assets']
}
```

Also your mock GraphicsRenderer won't be initialized with the Mock annotation as you are not using the MockitoJUnitRunner class. You have to initialize it like this in setUp().

```
renderer = Mockito.mock(GraphicsRenderer.class);
```

Comment: RobolectricGradleTestRunner was deprecated in version 3.1.1, @JaredBurrows . See stackoverflow.com/a/36564971/1848826

Answer (score 0):

Please specify android manifest via @Config annotation to your test