# RobolectricGradleTestRunner vs RobolectricTestRunner.class

Tags: robolectric

In roboelectric when you write your test class you have declare the @RunWith annotation of which there is RobolectricGradleTestRunner and RobolectricTestRunner.class. What is the difference and which one should we use ? Why is there 2 in the first place. If I use RobolectricTestRunner then it does not work for me it says some weird error like :

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."
```

However this seems to go away if I use RobolectricGradleTestRunner.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**RobolectricTestRunner** was first and is for maven based projects.

**RobolectricGradleTestRunner** was for gradle based projects because some paths have changed.
Since robolectric 3.1.1 this is not more necessary and is now deprecated.

For more details see also http://robolectric.org/getting-started/

Comment: RobolectricGradleTestRunner is deprecated [in 3.1.1] and uses should be replaced with RobolectricTestRunner -- https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/3.0-to-3.1-Upgrade-Guide

Comment: `RobolectricGradleTestRunner` has been removed as of 3.3

Comment: I am getting an error: **No such manifest file: build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky You're using an older version of Robolectric - update it. Latest version as I'm writing this is 3.5.1.